# How to find dielectric constants of ferroelectric materials experimentally?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, dielectric

What is the procedure to find out dielectric constant of barium titanate at different temperatures ?

Comment: This probably has answer [here](http://www.kps.or.kr/home/kor/journal/library/downloadPdf.asp?articleuid=%7BA583CDB8-78E4-44D7-B93E-4CF1A0C1D164%7D)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this requires an LCR (inductance, capacitance, resistance) meter, an oven/furnace/hotplate, and a thermocouple.  With an LCR meter, you can measure the capacitance as well as the loss tangent, $ \delta $ at the same time.  If you attach a thermocouple to the sample, and ramp the temperature slowly (less than 1 Celcius/min), you can measure the capacitance and loss tangent at each temperature.  It is best to use a oven/furnace that allows you to both the final desired temperature, and the ramp rate.  If you ramp too quickly, the pyroelectric currents generated by your sample can cause error in your LCR measurement.

If the LCR meter and thermocouple reader can be computer controlled, you can automate the entire process.

Barium titanate has more than one Curie temperature, where the dielectric constant, and hence capacitance, will be at a local maximum.  The only Curie temperature for barium titanate above room temperature is at roughly 120 Celcius.

The dielectric constant at each temperature of your material can easily be calculated from the capacitance at each temperature as long as you know the geometry of your sample.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitance bridge setup is good. One branch contains the known variable capacitance and a resistor. The other arm a resistor and the ferroelectric material. Adjust the known for null output.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward. All you need to do is measure the capacitance of the sample at constant frequency and at different temperatures.

Imagine the sample as a parallel plate capacitor of thickness D and area A.
Now Dielectric constant E = C D/A. With these calues you can plot the values w.r.t different temperatures and arrive at your curie temperature if that what you are looking at.

Now the trick is to measure the capacitance of the sample. You have arrive at a simple circuit to convert input voltage and measure the unknown capacitance.
[image]

One such configuration is shown above. You can tweak the R value to fit the capacitance in your digital multimeter.